Why is my BIOS not detecting the hard drive where is Ubuntu installed?
I have an acer travel mate laptop with windows and I wanted to also have Ubuntu, so I downloaded the 22.04.3 image and used rufus to make a booteable USB. Then I proceed with the instalation in one of my hard drives, I have two (one for Windows and other for Ubuntu). I manually create the partitions /boot, swap, / and /home and everything is fine. Then I restart the laptop and instead of loading me into grub to select he required OS it keeps loading Windows 10. I thought that it was the boot priority in the BIOS and then I noticed it, the hard drive where I installed Ubuntu is not in the boot priority. My main drive (Windows) is the Gigabyte one and the Toshiba is for Ubuntu. Here is a picture:

How can I make recognizable the drive?
Edit 
I have made some discoveries. If the bios mode is changed to legacy, the Toshiba disk appears in the boot priority list:

But it is not detected by the boot manager:

If the bios is in UEFI mode, the boot manager only detects the windows partition:

Also,I tried to reinstall ubuntu and this where the partitions detected:

You can see that the EFI partition is VFAT i don't know why because it was fat32 when I installed it for the firs time. And this is how I left it:


Is the partition type of the drive GPT or MBR?

GPT and the Gigabyte is a nvmie and the Toshiba a HDD

I also thought about that, but then why is not booting if is above of the windows drive?

Is fast start up disabled in Windows? Worth making sure you shut the computer down completely and then start it. I suspect that’s not the problem but do check!

HDD should be gpt with an ESP - efi system partition. If you used old BIOS/MBR configuration, you may have to reset system to boot in Legacy/BIOS/CSM boot mode to boot Ubuntu and switch back to boot Windows. All systems need to be in same boot mode or all UEFI or all old BIOS (really only for systems over 10 years old).

@Will yes, disabled both in windows and bios

@oldfred both drives are GPT. If i execute diskpart list both appears with a * in the GPT column

You say you manually partitioned the drive, but you didn’t include an ESP partition in your list. Did you create one? If so, it should be formatted as FAT32 and flagged as ESP. 500mb is a good recommended size and more than you’ll need.

@mpboden ok, this is strange. I plugged the usb with the image and tried to reinstall ubuntu. In the part where you can manually partition the drive it showed that there was 5 sda, the boot, the efi, the swap, the / and the /home but  the mounting point column was empty in all of them. Also, the efi (/boot/efi) partition (that is automatically created when you create the /boot partition) was VFAT and not FAT32 but wen I installed Ubuntu it said FAT32.

I managed to solve it, but I am not sure of what I have done. Here are the steps:

Instead of installing ubuntu I used kubuntu (I supose that you can use ubuntu).
Put the bios in legacy mode. It is posible that this is not necesary but it worked for me because in UEFI mode the disk where Kubuntu is installed was not being detected.
In the part of manual partition put the EFI partition FIRST. I think that is here where I screwed up.

And that is all.
